# Javascript Modules/Decoupling with DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm currently working on parts of a large Javascript application that deals a lot with DOM elements. I wanted to start making modules/start decoupling some of the code. I found some decent examples but one of the things I can't figure out is how to I create the DOM elements and interact with them? Should the Javascript be responsible for creating the DOM elements or should the Javascript take in a reference to the DOM elements or should the Javascript just assume that the elements will be there?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated and if I'm incorrect in anyway I'd appreciate the corrections :)

Comment: You may want to check out the jQuery library, here: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: in any case it's smart to check if the DOM elements are really there before you try to interact with them. But whether you create them using JS or just reference them is really up to your situation. If the DOM elements will always be there, you can just reference them (after having created them with HTML or PHP), but if you need to create DOM elements on the fly only when certain criteria are met, then you can use JS to create them.. It's hard to say what's best based on just the information we have here.

Comment: @myfunkyside thanks! I apologize for not posting any specific code, this was a general question. However, I feel your comment answers my question perfectly. Would you mind making it an answer so I can mark this as complete?

Comment: I'd be glad to:) Finally someone who understands the value of a solution beyond their own sake! (And obviously I don't mind the extra pennies:D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always smart to check if the DOM elements are really there before you try to interact with them.
But whether you create them using JS or just reference them is really up to your situation:

- If the DOM elements will always be there, you can just reference them (after having created them with HTML or PHP).
- But if you need to create DOM elements on the fly, only when certain criteria are met, then you can use JS to create them.

To be sure what the best approach would be, we'd have to be familiair with the specifics of your situation.